# how to get all child data from firebase from two tables

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from two tables in a database. But with child it is not working

I have this:

```
offers{
  "id" : {
    "quantity": "50%"
    "store" : {
      "id" : true
    }
}
"store":{
   "id":{
     address:"location"
     "users":{
        "id": true
     }
   }
}
"users" : {
  "name": "tom",
  "lastname": "levine"
}
```

this is my structured data I want to get all child data from my table something like this:

```
{
  "quantity":"50%",
  "store":{
    address:"location",
     "users":{
        "name": "tom",
        "lastname": "levine"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have this

```
const db = firebase.database();
db.ref('offers').child(id).once('value', (data) =>{
  console.log(data.val())
}
```

but if I add another .child(store) then just return the stores id of that offer

I have the offer id, the store Id that I want and all the users if the have name tom for example.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

**You should use a different structure for your database. NoSQL is more performant if you store data like you want to retrieve it.**

But you can do what you want with something like that :

(It's just an example, you probably need to update and fix this code)

```
db.ref("offers").child(id).once("value", function(snapshot) {
    var offerKey = snapshot.key;
    var offerValue = snapshot.val();

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var offerChildKey = childSnapshot.key;
        var offerChildData = childSnapshot.val();

        var quantity = offerChildData.quantity;
        var store = offerChildData.store;

        // Use quantity

        Object.keys(store).forEach(function (storeKey) {
            db.ref("store").child(storeKey).once("value", function(snapshot) {
                var storeKey = snapshot.key;
                var storeValue = snapshot.val();

                var address = storeValue.address;
                var users = storeValue.users;

                // Use address

                Object.keys(users).forEach(function (userKey) {
                    db.ref("users").child(userKey).once("value", function(snapshot) {
                        var userKey = snapshot.key;
                        var userValue = snapshot.val();

                        var name = userValue.name;
                        var lastname = userValue.lastname;

                        // Use name and lastname
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```